# Relation between generator polynomial and codeword in a cyclic code

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclic-groups, coding-theory

I'm trying to solve the following exercise, but I can't use an hypothesis.

> Let $F$ be a finite field and $a(x)$ a poly of degree $n$ over $F[x]$. Let $C$ the *smallest* cyclic code of length $n$ over $F$ with $a(x)$ as codeword, and let $g(x)$ the generator poly. Show that $g(x)=\text{G.C.D} (a(x),x^n-1)$

---

By definition, I know that $g|x^n - 1$ and $g$ has degree $n-k$.  Also, since $a(x)$ is codeword, then $a(x)=f(x) g(x)$, for some $f(x)$ of degree $n-k$, and hence $g|a(x)$.

Now I'm supposed to use the fact that $C$ is the **smallest** cyclic code that contains $a$ and that $a$ has degree $n$, but I really can't figure it out how two use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(By the way, I think the original problem is misstated. I think they mean "the degree of $a(x)$ is *less* than $n$.)

This is all just the picture that cyclic codes of length $n$ correspond to ideals in $F[x]/(x^n-1)$, and the fact that $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain.

The interpretation of the GCD in a PID is exactly: $g=\gcd(a,b)$ if and only if $(g)$ is the smallest ideal containing both $(a)$ and $(b)$.

And so you have it:

> $(g(x))$ is the smallest ideal containing $(a(x))$ and $(x^n-1)$,

but this is also just saying

> $(g(x))/(x^n-1)=(a(x), x^n-1)/(x^n-1)$.

So $(g(x))/(x^n-1)$ is the smallest cyclic code of length $n$ containing the word corresponding to $a(x)$.

Comment: thanks @rschwieb, but I really can't understand why $g(x)$ is the smallest ideal containing $(a(x))$ (and $(x^n-1)$.

Comment: That is literally the definition of gcd in a PID, if you think about it.  “Contains means divides” and a greater divisor is a smaller container

Comment: It's clear the idea now... just one point: how am I using the fact that $a(x)$ has degree $n$? Also, how are you sure that $(g)$ is an ideal of the quotient ring $F[x]/(x^n-1)$ ? @rschwieb

Comment: Is this because there's a bijection between the ideals of $F[x]/(x^n-1)$ and the ideals of $F[x]$ containing $(x^n-1)$?

Comment: @bobinthebox I don't see that $a(x)$'s degree matters at all. I think the question probably meant "less than $n$".  Yes, this is using the correspondence principle.

Comment: So, just to summarize: $(g)$ is the smallest ideal **of $F[x]$** containing $(a(x))$ and $(x^n-1)$. As there's the aforementioned ideal correspondence, $(\bar{g}(x))$ is the smallest ideal of **$F[x]/(x^n-1)$** with that property. As it is an ideal of  the quotien ring, it is a cyclic code (the smallest by definition of G.C.D). Now everything should be okay, right? This is an important detail to fix (it was not clear at all to me at the beginning).

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: @bobinthebox I re-wrote incorporating what I think is tickling your spider-sense.